# Shading a block that my mouse is over

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code that creates a memory game. I need to make it so that when my mouse is over a block it shades that block to a different color. I am writing the code in javascript. Whenever I try something is just says string is not a function. I am writing in khan academy and the code is mouseOver="this.color='black'"; Can anyone please help me?

```
draw = function() {
if (delayStartFC && (frameCount - delayStartFC) > 30) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        if (!tiles[i].isMatch) {
            tiles[i].drawFaceDown();
        }
    }
    flippedTiles = [];
    delayStartFC = null;
    // commented no loop because the timer stops working if this is enabled.
    mouseOver="this.color='black';" 
    // noLoop();
}
```

Comment: The rest of the code isn't visible here, so I'm not sure what the specific problem is.

Comment: What is the full line of code, not just a snipplet of it.

Comment: I'd say you're main problem is that you're doing it in JS. What about this CSS `element:hover{background-color: black;}`

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
<div onmouseover="Color(this,'black')"></div>

function Color(obj, color){
   obj.style.background=color;
}
```

hope it's useful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.style.backround='color'` instead of `this.color='color'`.  Try the below code:

```html
<div style="background:red;" onmouseover="this.style.background='blue';" onmouseout="this.style.background='red'">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put the code inline, it can get messy, so extracting it would be helpful like below:
The "selector" is whatever div or class or id you want to turn black on the mouse hover action.

```
$('selector').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually put events like mouseover in event listeners, rather than in the HTML mouseover attribute. If you're looking to do it in pure JavaScript, try this:

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#000";});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";});
```

You can also just accomplish this with CSS:

```
#test {
background-color: #FFF;
}

#test:hover {
background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are looking at the "[Project:Memory++](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-games-visualizations/memory-game/p/project-memory)" page, so I'll work from there.

If you look at the function above draw, it's called mouseClicked, you'll notice that it has a way of checking if a card is under the mouse:

```
 mouseClicked = function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
         if (tiles[i].isUnderMouse(mouseX, mouseY)) { //this line designates a tile under the mouse
         // draw the tile, tiles[i], with a color over it.
```

After you've found which tile to color, you'll need to write a function to change it, either by changing the image that the tile shows or by giving it an overlay. There are a few good ideas in the other threads, but I would stick with what you've been given during your other projects on Khan Academy.